# Mysql Rollback database?

Tags: mysql

I have deleted the database accidentally using the drop command in mysql . is there any way i can rollback it? is there any particular command?. Please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restore from a drop database command using a mysql binary log?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88800/how-do-i-restore-from-a-drop-database-command-using-a-mysql-binary-log)

Comment: maybe you should accept some answers as well.. people are trying to help you, using their time. respect that!

Answer (score 4):

No, and now you know what backup is about :D

Comment: I have a backup file. but i don't have permission to restore.

Comment: if you have a backup is perfect, but then is not an mysql problem anymore, is a permission issues. contact your provider and get the permissions.